# how to create 3D model based on a [x,y,z] matrix

Tags: python, 3d

I am doing some medical image processing and modeling things. I am new to this, and want to do it with python since I know python get my libs to do the work. My question is I have many [x,y] matrix representing the images of the body, and the images are continuous, so I can get a [x,y,z] matrix representing the body. Is there any way I can get a 3D model from the [x,y,z] matrix? If it is possible, if I get another dimension, representing time, could I get a dynamic 3D model?

Comment: Do these images have a transparency or solid background? i.e each pixel that isn't a part of the body is the same as all the other pixels not part of the body? If so, I may be able to provide a technique, assuming you know how to construct a 3d model with vertices

Comment: yes, the background color is black, but I don't know how to construct a 3D model with vertices. I thought in python there might be some libs that could do the work, although I don't know about it yet.

Comment: If you are serious about getting this done, if you provide me with a set of textures (like you described), I could try making the program and then explain it

Comment: I am serious about it. Do you have any solution in your mind? Coding in python? I got the CT slices (the dicom files). But it's pretty huge.

Comment: I'm not to savvy at python but this is the gist of my idea:

1: for each y value(height) test from the minimum and maximum x values stepping toward the middle until an inconsistency is found, this gets the width of the model at each height, do this for each z(depth slice).

Once you have every point, make a quad(just 2 triangles) with the point below and pair it with the same point in the next slice. This will create a mesh basically vacuum packed around the scan.

Comment: I would make it in C++ and OpenGL, but it could be written as pseudo code pretty easily